# how to send an object JdbcRowSet from server to the client?

Tags: java

//This is server:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(99999);
ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

Socket sock = ser.accept();

JdbcRowSet rowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl();

rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"); 
rowSet.setUsername(userName); 
rowSet.setPassword(password);
rowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM tablename"); 
rowSet.execute(); 
System.out.println("nome \tcognome"); 

while (rowSet.next()) {
System.out.println(rowSet.getString("nome") + "\t" + rowSet.getString("cognome")); }

outToClient.writeObject(rowSet);
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//This is client:

```
public class Client{

sock = new Socket("localhost",99999);

inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

while(true){

giocatore = (Giocatore)inFromServer.readObject();
System.out.println("nome: " + giocatore.getNome());
System.out.println("cognome: " + giocatore.getCognome());}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The table is fine printed in the server, but the client can't received the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the RowSet implementation is serializable or not, but the maximum socket can't be higher than 65535.